# Can we say "Hail to someone/somebody" in a humorous way?

Tags: phrase-usage

Following this interesting [thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/26982), Can I use this phrase in a humorous way, for instance to mock somebody or to be sarcasm?

> **Hail to the rich people** in this world! They can buy everything!

That's my best attempt to make an example. Does it sound unnatural?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a native English speaker, I’d say **yes**.

This could be said sarcastically, and I’m sure people would still understand it. The only thing is you would have to be careful on how you say it: depending on the tone, it could be taken as serious.